# Convert integer numbers into a specific float numbers in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has random integer numbers and I want to convert them into float numbers but I want to put **decimal point** after **first two digits** only. Following is my array:

```
[143] => Array
    (
        [0] => 723579
        [1] => 112338261
    )

[144] => Array
    (
        [0] => 723575
        [1] => 11233847
    )

[145] => Array
    (
        [0] => 723575
        [1] => 11233
    )
```

And I want the output to be the following.

```
[143] => Array
    (
        [0] => 72.3579
        [1] => 11.2338261
    )

[144] => Array
    (
        [0] => 72.3575
        [1] => 11.233847
    )

[145] => Array
    (
        [0] => 72.3575
        [1] => 11.233
    )
```

I think that I can manipulate it through string modification first and convert it into float number. Is there any easiest or simple way to manipulate it in PHP?

Comment: The numbers in your result are floats, not int.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what a "round number" is. Your input contains round numbers, the output contains fractions.

Comment: i dont realy understand the correct name of the number format in english. but is there any way to manipulate the array to those format?

Comment: Yes there is. I put it in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `foreach` loops. Use reference variables so you can modify the original arrays. Insert a `.` after the second digit, then convert that to a float.

```
foreach ($array as &$nested_array) {
    foreach ($nested_array as &$val) {
        $val = floatval(substr($val, 0, 2) . "." . substr($val, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: i think i need to read more about format number in english, thanks a lot